# How to read values from one of custom Queries in MS Access VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a MS ACCESS query called `Query11` that sums up amounts.

Let's say it's got `SUM_WEEKLY` and `SUM_MONTHLY` as a field in `Query11`

In VBA, how could I get each value?

I have tried to get them with the codes below and it did not work.

```
Dim dbMyDB As Database
Dim rsMyRS As Recordset

Set dbMyDB = CurrentDb
Set rsMyRS = dbMyDB.OpenRecordset("Query11")

MsgBox rsMyRS("SUM_WEEKLY")
MsgBox rsMyRS("SUM_MONTHLY")
```

[image: Query11]

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820966.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work, and you don't tell the error, but try to be a bit more explicit:

```
Dim dbMyDB As DAO.Database
Dim rsMyRS As DAO.Recordset

Set dbMyDB = CurrentDb
Set rsMyRS = dbMyDB.OpenRecordset("Query11")

' Check that a record exists.
MsgBox CStr(rsMyRS.RecordCount)

MsgBox rsMyRS("SUM_WEEKLY").Value
MsgBox rsMyRS("SUM_MONTHLY").Value
```

Comment: Now I am getting Item not found in this collection (3265 run-time error)

Comment: Then probably either field "SUM_WEEKLY" or "SUM_MONTHLY"  is missing in your query11.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Query11")

' Check a record exists
If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
 MsgBox "SUM_WEEKLY = " & rs!SUM_WEEKLY
 MsgBox "SUM_MONTHLY = " & rs!SUM_MONTHLY
Else
 MsgBox "Recordset has no records"
End If
```